# Can't find and fix my seg fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> "*Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x000000000040073b in concat (nextstr=0x7fffffffee66 "the",
>     longstr=0x7fffffffe750 "", i=0x0) at main.c:24
>   24  printf("%c -> %c\n", nextstr[j], longstr[*i]);
>   (gdb)"

```
// define max for command line
#define MAX_CHARS 1000
#include <stdio.h>
int concat(char[], char[], int *);
void printreverse(char[], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char longstring[MAX_CHARS] = { '\0' };
    int i = 0, j;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("%s requires command-line args\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= argc; j++)
    {
        if (concat(argv[j], longstring, i))
            return 1;
    }

    i--;
    longstring[i] = '\0';    //delete trailing space
    printf("%s\n", longstring);
}

int concat(char nextstr[], char longstr[], int *i)
{
    int j = 0;

    while (nextstr[j] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c -> %c\n", nextstr[j], longstr[*i]);
        longstr[*i] = nextstr[j];

        (*i)++;
        j++;

        if (*i > MAX_CHARS)
        {
            printf("Error: Input is too long!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (j > 0)
    {
        if ((*i) + 2 > MAX_CHARS)
        {
            printf("Error: Input is too long!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        longstr[*i] = ' ';
        longstr[(*i) + 1] = '\0';
        (*i)++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pointer error most likely

> "This takes a command line argument is checks the length but there's a seg fault"

I think the error is on line 33
but I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: People are more likely to look/help with proper code indenting. Also, you've interspersed your commentary with the code. The trailing part of your code is _outside_ the code block which is why it comes up yellow [as in a quoted passage], which is kicked off by a `>` outside of a code block.

Comment: In main, you are passing i to concat().  First i is an int, not an int*, Second since i is initialized to 0, you are passing a null pointer.  So (*i)++ with a null pointer would generate a seg fault.

Comment: I don't really know c at all i'm learning so can you show me in the code with comments

Comment: I don't have to allocate memory using malloc to create memory for the pointer to hold the char

Comment: Try changing this line "if(concat(argv[j], longstring, &i)) return 1;" in main().  The &i will pass the address of i to concat()

Comment: I formated your question, but your line number is and was not helpful please replace the line number with a citation of the line so it is clear what you are referencing

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that is causing the crash is in your for loop:

```
for(j = 1; j <= argc; j++){
    if(concat(argv[j], longstring, i)) return 1;
}
```

Since concat's third parameter is an int *, you need to pass a pointer to i.  Also, you are iterating through the loop one too many times.  If argc is 2, then the program name is in argv[0], and your argument is in argv[1].  So, change the loop to this:

```
for(j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
    if (concat(argv[j], longstring, &i))
        return 1;
}
```